# Which adjective does 'pills', 'powder' and 'liquid' belong to?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, word-request

My native language is Spanish and today I was wondering how do you say 'presentación' referring to the type of presentation the medicine come from. For example, if you go to the drug store to buy a medicine you can ask if you have it in injectable form or in pills. How can you ask in which presentations the medicine came from? It is ok to say 'presentation' as a literal translation from the Spanish or it have a different word to refer to it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The word used for this in English is **form.** "Presentation" is a false cognate.

The Wikipedia page on the concept [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dosage_form) used the longer term "dosage form," but in practice we wouldn't use such a specific phrase unless we had to disambiguate with other meanings of the word.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Amoxicilin - British National Formulary - **Medicinal forms** - 
There can be variation in the licensing of different medicines containing the same drug.

Capsule, Oral suspension, Powder for solution for injection, Powder

Comment: Probably second best, but you could also use "Type", e.g. "What type of medicine is it? A pill, injection or oral?"

Comment: "Form" is the correct term, but non-professionals would probably use "type" instead in British English, even though "type" has a different official meaning For example different "types" of blood pressure medication are diuretics, beta blockers, ACE inhibitors, etc, not pills, oral liquids, injectable liquids, etc.

Comment: @alephzero the technical term for the different "types" of blood pressure medication is **classes**. Type would only be used by lay people for this. https://www.heart.org/en/health-topics/high-blood-pressure/changes-you-can-make-to-manage-high-blood-pressure/types-of-blood-pressure-medications